# How do we deal with links to piracy, porn and other potentially malicious sites?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930859/need-help-with-first-row-sports) (10k+ reputation necessary to see it).

It contains a link to a piracy streaming site full of ads, pop-ups, etc.

What is SE policy for keeping this type of links here? Do we really want to advertise this type of services?

Is it OK to post a question like "This porn site doesn't open in Ubuntu, but opens in Windows"?

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137846/280883

Comment: OK, I will tell spammers how to post spam correctly here ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 that's not what he meant and you know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***[Refer to the Content Policy for StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) for what is or is not permitted.***

To quote [this question on SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137846/policy-on-links-either-directly-or-indirectly-to-pirate-content) regarding pirated content:

> It's not our job to police pirated content.
>
> You changed the link back to text but someone could just as easily
>   copy-paste the link and have access to the pirated content. Your heart
>   was in the right place but it is not our job as Stack Exchange users
>   to uphold someone else's copyright laws. **No need to flag here...**
>
> If the OP so desperately wanted those links to still be clickable then
>   so-be-it.
>
> You were 100% right not to start an edit war over something so
>   trivial.

That said, if we catch it as moderators we *may* do something about it.  Flag it if you *really* think it's a problem, but keep in mind we handle things on a case-by-case basis.  It's usually *not* necessarily flag-worthy, because you can just edit out links and leave comments about such evil links.

This in mind, we need to keep in mind that sites which are generic 'file upload' sites, while used for pirated content and malware, are *not necessarily* used solely for distribution of malware, we have to look at it on a case-by-case basis.  Usually such 'upload sites' are not exactly the most reliable, nor is the linked content, so as moderators (or at least me as a moderator) we tend to recommend to individual users that they *not* use general upload sites.

This is a *hugely* broad category though so case-by-case basis.  Any questions, ask a moderator.  We usually lurk in chat.  You can open a Meta post if you wish, but eh.

---

With regards to **pornography or mature adult imagery**:

We do not permit links to such content per the SE TOS and Terms of Use.  Direct links to the content will be deleted, and repeated offenses of the TOS can result in moderation against a given user.  Again, generic upload sites may be handled on a case by case basis.

---

With regards to malware, if you flag links going directly to malware we'll delete it.  However, again, generic sites, case-by-case basis.

Comment: The problem is that the whole point of spammers is to place a link to some highly visited site. But this looks reasonable.

Comment: But still this type of sites ("free streaming") usually are full of all kinds of malware. It is not the piracy that was the most important part.

Comment: @Pilot6 as i said multiple times - case by case basis.  We aren't here to police all content on the 'net.  We *are* capable of handling things against terms of use, but it's not necessarily our job to police every single link that comes past us.  Also as I said, flag if you consider it an issue.  We'll handle everything case by case.